# How it is possible to use config array file adapter?

Tags: phalcon

I found in documentation that it is possible to have following code:

```
// config.php
$settings = array();

// index.php
require_once('config.php');
$config = new \Phalcon\Config($settings);
```

But is it possible to create config not with array, but with filename that contains an array?
I mean the following:

```
// config.php
return array(....);

// index.php
$config = new \Phalcon\Config\Array('config.php');
```

Or smth like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not feasible. However you can easily extend Phalcon\Config\Array as follows:

```
class MyConfig extends \Phalcon\Config
{
    public function __construct($file)
    {
        if (!file_exists($file))
        {
            throw new \Phalcon\Config\Exception(
                'File was not found'
            );
        }

        $data = require($file);

        if (!is_array($data))
        {
            throw new \Phalcon\Config\Exception(
                'File supplied does not contain an array'
            );
        }

        parent::__construct($data);
    }
}
```

The above should get you what you need